# Fire only when clicking on parent element JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 collapsible nested inside each other

[image]

When clicking on Test 7, it closes both the BRAND and test 7 accordions

I have this JavaScript code where "mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox" is the className of the parent element (BRAND)

```
const mobile_navbar_accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox");

for (let i = 0; i < mobile_navbar_accordion.length; i++) {
   let checkbox = mobile_navbar_accordion[i];
   checkbox.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active");
   })
}
```

Solutions I tried:

1. Adding `e.stopPropagation();` inside the click event
2. Replacing e.currentTarget with e.target but the click event is never working on the parent element, I tested this with the following code

   if (e.target == e.currentTarget) console.log("clicked on parent");

   else console.log("clicked on children")

I also tried

```
if(e.target == this) console.log("clicked on parent")
else console.log("clicked on children")
```

In both cases it returned "clicked on children"

I replaced e.currentTarget with this

```
this.classList.toggle('..')
```

And in the console I received this error

[image]

4. 

```
pointer-events: none;
```

In css for the children box, also for children title + content separately but it caused 2 issues, first stopping (Test 5, Test 6) from firing the link event. However it still didn't stop closing the parent when clicking on children box or children elements

```js
const mobile_navbar_accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox");
const mobile_navbar_accordion_grandchildren = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren");

for (let i = 0; i < mobile_navbar_accordion.length; i++) {
  let checkbox = mobile_navbar_accordion[i];
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", (e) => 
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active")
  )
}
for (let i = 0; i < mobile_navbar_accordion_grandchildren.length; i++) {
  let checkbox = mobile_navbar_accordion_grandchildren[i];
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", (e) => 
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active")
  )
}
```

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren{
  width: 600px;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox,
.mobile-nav_box {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

/* For + sign after each collapsible title */
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label::before,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren::before
{
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 18px;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox.active .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label::before,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren.active .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren::before
{
  content: "-";
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content__grandchildren
{
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.1s !important;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content__grandchildren{
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox.active .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren.active .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content__grandchildren{
  height: max-content;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.mobile-nav__links,
.mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren h5{
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: #3c3c3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav_accordion">
  <div class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox">
    <label class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label">
      BRAND
    </label>
    <div class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content">
      <ul class="navigation-item-children--top-level">
        <li>
          <a class="mobile-nav__links" href="#">
            <span>
              Hello World 1 
            </span>
          </a>

          <!-- HERE GOES THE GRANDCHILDS -->
          <div class="mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren">
            <div class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren">
              <label class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren">
                Test 1
              </label>
              <div class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content__grandchildren">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a class="mobile-nav__links" href="#">
                      Hello world
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add a working example of your issue? A tip is to add a executable code snippet

Comment: @Tushar I just added a code snippet, please try clicking on brand then test (the style is messed up a bit)

Comment: you would have to add `e.stopPropagation();` to the child element click event to stop the event bubbling up to the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can basically change your script to the provided version below.

```js
const mobile_navbar_accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label");
const mobile_navbar_accordion_grandchildren = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren");

for (let i = 0; i < mobile_navbar_accordion.length; i++) {
  let checkbox = mobile_navbar_accordion[i];
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    // getting the parent element to add active
    e.currentTarget.closest('.mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox').classList.toggle("active")
 })
}
for (let i = 0; i < mobile_navbar_accordion_grandchildren.length; i++) {
  let checkbox = mobile_navbar_accordion_grandchildren[i];
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // getting the parent element to add active
    e.currentTarget.closest('.mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren').classList.toggle("active")
  } )
}
```

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren{
  width: 600px;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox,
.mobile-nav_box {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

/* For + sign after each collapsible title */
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label::before,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren::before
{
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 18px;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox.active .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label::before,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren.active .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren::before
{
  content: "-";
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content__grandchildren
{
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.1s !important;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content__grandchildren{
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
.mobile-nav_accordion .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox.active .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content,
.mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren.active .mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content__grandchildren{
  height: max-content;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.mobile-nav__links,
.mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren h5{
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: #3c3c3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav_accordion">
  <div class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox">
    <label class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label">
      BRAND
    </label>
    <div class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content">
      <ul class="navigation-item-children--top-level">
        <li>
          <a class="mobile-nav__links" href="#">
            <span>
              Hello World 1 
            </span>
          </a>

          <!-- HERE GOES THE GRANDCHILDS -->
          <div class="mobile-nav_accordion__grandchildren">
            <div class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox__grandchildren">
              <label class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-label__grandchildren">
                Test 1
              </label>
              <div class="mobile-nav_accordion-contentbox-content__grandchildren">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a class="mobile-nav__links" href="#">
                      Hello world
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```